# "Guidelines" for juvenile felony in ohio

Tags: sentencing

After finding some things such as [this](http://winningwithbinning.com/ohio-sentencing-chart/) that kind of shows a guideline for sentencing and fines for felonies I was wondering if there was some sort of guidelines that could apply for a minor to commit a felony?

Answer (score 1):

Alright after a lot of searching before hand I finally phrased the search right to find [this](http://www.johnsonlegalofohio.com/ohio-juvenile-crime-penalties/).. Sorry to sound like I don't google things, but I'd been searching for a while. I do hope this helps others looking for this, as it is tricky to find.

"A serious youth offender (SYO) sentence combines a sentence typically given to a juvenile with a sentence that is typically reserved only for adults convicted of a felony or misdemeanor. Several factors are used by the court to determine whether such a sentence is appropriate. These include:

- Whether the crime was an offense of violence if committed by an adult;
- Whether the juvenile had a firearm while committing the offense; and
- Whether the juvenile has a prior conviction for a serious crime."

Classes of felonies in Delaware (and generally) Ohio (or non-classed such as murder)

**Aggravated Murder & Murder**

- If the juvenile is 14-17 years old – mandatory SYO sentence
- If the juvenile is 10-13 years old – discretionary SYO sentence
- If the juvenile is under 10 years old – up to 90 days in a detention facility
- Fine up to $2000

**Attempted Aggravated Murder or Attempted Murder**

- If the juvenile is 14-17 years old – mandatory SYO sentence
- 10-13 years old – discretionary SYO sentence
- under 10 years old – up to 90 days in a detention facility
- Maximum $2000 fine

**1st Degree Felony**

- 16-17 years old – mandatory SYO sentence if factors are present; discretionary SYO sentence if no factors are present
- 14-15 years old – discretionary SYO sentence
- 10-13 years old – discretionary SYO if factors are present
- under 10 years old – up to 90 days in a detention facility
- Maximum $1500 fine

**2nd Degree Felony**

- 14-17 years old – discretionary SYO sentence
- 12-13 – discretionary SYO sentence if factors are present
- under 12 years old – up to 90 days in a detention facility
- Max Fine: $1000

**3rd Degree Felony**

- 16-17 years old – discretionary SYO sentence
- 14-15 – discretionary SYO sentence if factors are present
- under 14 years old – up to 90 days in a detention facility
- Fine up to $750

**4th Degree Felony**

- 16-17 years old – discretionary SYO sentence if factors are present
- under 16 years old – up to 90 days in a detention facility
- $400 Max fine

**5th Degree Felony**

- 16-17 years old – discretionary SYO if factors are present
- under 16 years old – up to 90 days in a detention facility
- Max $500 Fine

Comment: Andrew, welcome to the site. We expect answers and questions to be self-contained, links are ok for amplifying but the gist should be put into the post. Partly because links die or change and partly because the stuff in the links can't be searched within the site.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit it and toss in the Gist in a bit.